# Accessing Ubuntu through RealVNC from my window laptop: Protocol error Message type 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I am trying to VNC into my Ubuntu Desktop from my laptop using Real VNC. Real VNC on my laptop sees the Ubuntu but it is not clearly visible. It displays a message

`Attempting to reconnect to VNC server...`

`Protocol error: invalid message type 20`

[image]

Comment: RDP and VNC are 2 different thigns.

Comment: Suggested in [this openmediavault forum posting](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/38149-new-openmediavault-kvm-plugin/&pageNo=5) _"To fix this change Picture Quality from Automatic to High, in the properties of the connection. Then re-connect."_

Comment: @Peregrino69 Isn't Real VNC is used for Remote Desktoping into another computer? I followed so many steps, articles to make Ubuntu remote accessible. None worked or all confused me a lot. So, I installed Ubuntu fresh again by erasing old one. I want to start from the scratch. I appreciate if you could refer a link or video that successfully helps me do it. Thanks

Comment: LOL yes :-D [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) and [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) are both used for remote access, but they are different systems using different protocols. VNC is the one commonly used with Linux. There are a bunch of VNC servers and clients, so can't recommend any... [this RealVNC article](https://discover.realvnc.com/what-is-vnc-remote-access-technology) explains what it's all about. Did you try changing the resolution as the openmediavault posting suggested?